# Why do configuration folders have *.d in their name

Tags: etc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Many directories have a “.d” suffix/extension. What does it mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7648/many-directories-have-a-d-suffix-extension-what-does-it-mean)

Why do most of the folders in /etc/* end with *.d

I am just curious to know, why folders would have this ( extension? ).

[image]

Comment: You may find by using the search button that this question has already been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7648/many-directories-have-a-d-suffix-extension-what-does-it-mean Edit: I searched for "config folder with ".d" suffix"

Comment: Even if it's a duplicate, why downvote this question? It's a valid one.

Comment: Note, that there is no such thing "extension" in Unix (Linux included) - extensions are notion of CP/M and then DOS inherited this terminology but not UNIX systems -, dot is part of the file name, you can have even more, like "file.tar.gz" or things like "file........hello...this." etc. Though "." and ".." as names are special ones: this means the current and the parent directories. Also files (and directories) starting with "." are treated as "hidden" files, normally even "ls" does not show them only with using switch "-a".

Comment: @LGB Calling it extension (with a question mark) was also a part of the question; your comment could have been an answer, so my question still qualifies as a valid one. And I still don't understand why it was downvoted.

Comment: @LGB It's still common, and valid, to refer to the last dot-delimited part(s) of a filename as an extension, when the function is to act as a technical type or purpose annotation for the file. For example, when a .NET/Mono executable on Windows ends in `.exe` that's called an extension (it's just *part of the file name* in NTFS, too!), and when that file is brought over to an Ubuntu system, it is correct to call the `.exe` suffix an extension here, too. Furthermore, `.odt` is an extension, `.tar.gz` and the final `.gz` can both be called extensions (and `.tar.gz` can exist on Windows too!).

Answer (score 6):

The `.d` denotes a directory containing configuration files, as opposed to a single config file.

This applies to other configuration directories under `/etc` such as `/etc/apt.conf.d/`, `/etc/rc.d`